# How to create a CLOWN PASS for material selection in photoshop?

Tags: materials

I use photoshop for post processing my renders.
I would like to have a clown pass exported with the shadow, diff, and ao maps...
Is there a setting I'm missing ?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Dedicate render layer with material override

For this task I usually set up a dedicated *render layer*.

I render only the *emission pass* of the surfaces using a material that transform a given random number, one for each object, into a color of the color ramp.

To render all the objects with the same material without touching your original scene, you can use the *[Material box](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/post_process/layers.html?highlight=material%20override)* in the Layer panel of the Render Layers tab.

Here's a possible setup:

[image]

*Note (1): you need just 1 sample to achieve the final look, so it should not affect much your rendering time.*

*Note (2): this works "per object", not "per materials". For materials, I would use the Material ID pass, but that's not automated.*

Comment: Thanks. I think "per objects" will work perfectly. But do I need to apply the random emission color to all objects in the scene ?

Comment: You don't have to change your materials. You should only override them. This can be done automatically, and for the dedicated layer only, by using the material override option for the render layer. See the link in the answer for further details.